# Removing element from array: convert to list, remove element, convert back to array?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, list

In my program I have a class called Album. I have an Array my Album objects go into on creation. I need to let the user change the albumName of an Album later if they want to. I also need to let the user delete Albums from the Array if they want to. From what I understand, you can't just delete objects from Arrays, so it would be good if they were stored in a List, not an Array.

From what I understand of Lists (I haven't used them before this), I can't put the Album objects into a List instead of an Array on creation if I want to change a variable in the Album object later. I also can't just delete and replace the Album object with a new one in the List if I want to change the albumName, since the Album object will be storing an Array (myMusics) that would be lost if I did that.

So my question is, how do I allow a user to make changes to the Album objects while also letting them delete them? I think I'd have to change the Array they are stored in, to a List. Then delete the object fromt the List, then change the List it back into the same Array. Is this correct? How would I do this if it is the right way to go about this?

Also, if it helps/makes a difference, the Array containing the Albums will be created in Form1, the Album objects will be deleted from Form 1, but the changes to the albumName in the Album object will happen in Form2.

Any help is much appreciated. I'm pretty new to using c#, so an example of the code to help me understand would be fantastic. Thank you.

Album class:

```
public class Album
{
    public string albumName;
    private int totalMusics;
    private const int MAX_MUSICS = 100;
    private Music[] myMusics;

    public Album(string albumName)
    {
        this.albumName = albumName;
        totalMusics = 0;
        myMusics = new Music[MAX_MUSICS];
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use `List<Music>` instead of array

Comment: You _can_ change the name of your album if the album is in a List. So just use a List.

Comment: `Array.FindAll` is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From what I understand of Lists (I haven't used them before this), I
>   can't put the Album objects into a List instead of an Array on
>   creation if I want to change a variable in the Album object later.

This is only true for *structs*. Since you are using a (mutable) *class*, you will be able to change the properties of the objects while they are stored in a `List<Album>`.

So you *definitely* should be using a `List`.

Unless you want to be able to look up Albums by some field, for example by `AlbumName`. If so, you could use a `Dictionary<string, Album>` and use `AlbumName` for the key.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm getting the error:
'MusicCollection.Form1.AlbumList' cannot be used like a method, with this line:
formMain.AlbumList(formMain.AlbumsListBox.SelectedItem).albumName = NameTextBox.Text;
(formMain is how I reference Form1 in Form2) what am I doing wrong to change the Album's albumName?

Comment: AlbumList is declared at the very start of Form1 like this: public List<Album> AlbumList;

Comment: You must use the index operator, `[]`, not the function call `()`, like so: `formMain.AlbumList[formMain.AlbumsListBox.SelectedItem].albumName = ...`

Comment: Use SelectedIndex, not SelectedItem. Be aware that if no item is selected, SelectedIndex will be -1 which is out of range of the list, so test for this first.

Comment: Ah, thank you! That change, as well as changing SelectedItems to SelectedIndex seemed to work :): formMain.AlbumList[formMain.AlbumsListBox.SelectedIndex].albumName

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you store `Music` in `List<Music>` all along. Unlike other languages in `C#` `List` is actually a dynamically expandable array with constant indexing operation `[]`.

Still keep in mind this implies that deleting any element from the list other than the last one would mean extra operations to shift the elements. If you don't care about the order of Music in the `List` I suggest before deleting an Album you swap it with the last one in the `List` and then delete the last element in the `List`.